# Why does my dplyr percentile calculation not work with tidy evaluation?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I have a tibble with student test data, and I wish to convert these to percentiles using `dplyr`. For the sake of having a minimal example, imagine the following setup of three students.

```
require(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Cat"), Test = c(16, 13, 15))
```

The following code works and yields the desired output.

```
tbl %>% mutate(TestPercentile = cume_dist(Test) * 100)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Name   Test TestPercentile
  <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>
1 Alice    16          100  
2 Bob      13           33.3
3 Cat      15           66.7
```

However, I actually want to do it programmatically because there are many such columns.

```
colname <- "Test"
percname <- str_c(colname, "Percentile")
tbl %>% mutate({{percname}} := cume_dist({{colname}}) * 100)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Name   Test TestPercentile
  <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>
1 Alice    16            100
2 Bob      13            100
3 Cat      15            100
```

Why does `cume_dist` make the percentile 100 for all students when I try to use tidy evaluation like this? (And ideally, if I can be permitted a second question, how can I fix it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by programmatically you mean you want to write your own function, you can do it like this:

```
calculate_percentile <- function(data, colname) {

   data %>% 
    mutate("{{colname}}Percentile" := cume_dist({{colname}} * 100))

}

tbl %>% 
  calculate_percentile(Test)

 # A tibble: 3 x 3
  Name   Test TestPercentile
  <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>
1 Alice    16          1    
2 Bob      13          0.333
3 Cat      15          0.667
```

**Edit for multiple columns**
New Data

```
tbl <- tibble(Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Cat"), Test = c(16, 13, 15), Test_math = c(16, 30, 55), Test_music = c(3, 78, 34))
```

```
calculate_percentile <- function(data, colnames) {

  data %>% 

    mutate(across({{colnames}}, ~cume_dist(.) * 100, .names = "{col}Percentile"))

}

test_columns <- c("Test_math", "Test_music")
tbl %>% 
  calculate_percentile(test_columns) 

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Name   Test Test_math Test_music Test_mathPercentile Test_musicPercentile
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>               <dbl>                <dbl>
1 Alice    16        16          3                33.3                 33.3
2 Bob      13        30         78                66.7                100  
3 Cat      15        55         34               100                   66.7
```

Why does your solution not work? Because your solution applies `cume_dist` literally to the string "test":

```
tbl %>% mutate({{percname}} := print({{colname}}))

[1] "Test"
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Name   Test Test_math Test_music TestPercentile
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>         
1 Alice    16        16          3 Test          
2 Bob      13        30         78 Test          
3 Cat      15        55         34 Test
```

Why does this give a `TestPercentile` value of 100? Because `cume_dist` of "test" is 1:

```
cume_dist("test")
#[1] 1
```

So we need R to tell not to evaluate the string "test" per se but to look for a variable with this name, which we can do like this:

```
tbl %>% mutate({{percname}} := cume_dist(!!parse_quo(colname, env = global_env())) * 100)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Name   Test Test_math Test_music TestPercentile
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>          <dbl>
1 Alice    16        16          3          100  
2 Bob      13        30         78           33.3
3 Cat      15        55         34           66.7

#Check that this uses the values of "Test" and not "Test" per se:
tbl %>% mutate({{percname}} := print(!!parse_quo(colname, env = global_env())))

[1] 16 13 15
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Name   Test Test_math Test_music TestPercentile
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>          <dbl>
1 Alice    16        16          3             16
2 Bob      13        30         78             13
3 Cat      15        55         34             15
```

Comment: Thanks -- I see the issue is that I'm using quoted strings "Test" rather than literally typing Test. The problem is it is coming from a list of strings representing column names (in the actual code I'm trying to write, not this minimal example). The best I can see so far isn't super elegant: `tbl %>% mutate({{percname}} := cume_dist(tbl[[colname]]) * 100)`

Comment: Ok. Difficult to help without seeing your data. Maybe ask another question if you get stuck again.

Comment: Is it possible to make your function so that instead of taking Test, it takes a string like "Test" that might be passed from another source?

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't return the OP's expected output.

Comment: That aspect can be solved by putting the *100 outside the brackets of the cume_dist, so that it returns a percentile. Hence, I can't accept the question as answered, but as I mentioned the major issue is handling a string as input.

Comment: See updated answer with column names specified from another source

Comment: Thank you for the update. This is certainly an impressive solution to my second question of how to fix it. I would still be interested in an answer to the title question of "why does my solution not work?"

Comment: Sorry that got lost. See my updated answer for why your approach does not work. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Passing column name as string :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

return_percentile <- function(data, colname) {
   percname <- paste0(colname, "Percentile")
   data %>% mutate({{percname}} := cume_dist(!!sym(colname)) * 100)
}

tbl %>% return_percentile("Test")

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Name   Test TestPercentile
#  <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 Alice    16          100  
#2 Bob      13           33.3
#3 Cat      15           66.7
```

---

Passing column name unquoted :

```
return_percentile <- function(data, colname) {
  percname <- paste0(deparse(substitute(colname)), "Percentile")
  data %>% mutate({{percname}} := cume_dist({{colname}}) * 100)
}

tbl %>% return_percentile(Test)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Name   Test TestPercentile
#  <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 Alice    16          100  
#2 Bob      13           33.3
#3 Cat      15           66.7
```